# Getting "unused argument" when summarising a dataframe

Tags: r

I know nothing/zip/nada about programming in R, but we have been asked to run some code that summarizes a data frame (data table? not sure of lingo).  I am getting an error thrown on a particular line, and my googling isn't teaching me enough about R syntax for me to figure it out.

I am stepping through the R code using *RStudio v1.2.1335*, and the R version is *R x64 3.6.1*

A dataframe *dff* is created that contains a bunch of columns and has half hourly data for various nodes for approximately 4 years.  As a very simplified demo without all the columns something like:

```
datetime        node   year   load, generation, deltaSS ...
1/1/2014 00:00, ABC,   2014,   100,  50,          300    ...
1/1/2014 00:00, XYZ,   2014,   200,  150,         500    ...
1/1/2014 00:30, ABC,   2014,   125,  70,          355    ...
1/1/2014 00:30, ABC,   2014,   220,  150,         25     ...
:
1/1/2015 00:00, ABC,   2015,   200,  20,          200    ...
1/1/2015 00:00, XYZ,   2015,   400,  450,         400    ...
:
```

What I believe the code is trying to do is summarize a subset of these columns for specific groupings.  Some of the columns need to be simple summed, others need to be summed / 2 to convert into a different unit.  The grouping is by year and by node.

In other words, for each year and node, sum up (or sum/2) the values of some of the columns in the table.  Something like:

```
node   year   load, generation, deltaSS ...
ABC,   2014,   1000,  5000,     30000    ...
XYZ,   2014,   2000,  15000,    50000    ...
ABC,   2014,   1250,  7000,     35500    ...
ABC,   2014,   2200,  15000,    2500     ...
:
ABC,   2015,   2000,  2000,     20000    ...
XYZ,   2015,   4000,  45000,    40000    ...
:
```

The error I am getting is:

**Error in `[.data.frame`(dff, , .(generationMWh = sum(generation)/2, loadMWh = sum(load,  : 
  unused argument (by = .(modelyear, node))**

It seems strange that we're getting an error at all because apparently this code has been run and works (I only mention this in case it turns out to be a library version or something).

The code that throws the error is:

```
df <- dff[,.(generationMWh = sum(generation)/2, 
                 loadMWh = sum(load,na.rm = TRUE)/2,
                 deltaSS = sum(deltaSS,na.rm = TRUE), 
                 pos_deltaSS = sum(pos_deltaSS,na.rm = TRUE), 
                 neg_deltaSS = sum(neg_deltaSS,na.rm = TRUE), 
                 deltaCS = sum(deltaCS,na.rm = TRUE),
                 pos_deltaCS = sum(pos_deltaCS,na.rm = TRUE),
                 neg_deltaCS = sum(neg_deltaCS,na.rm = TRUE)
    ), by = .(modelyear,node)]
```

Can someone help me out here?   Perhaps if its not immediately obvious what the problem is, could there be another way to write R code that summarizes specific columns by groupings?

Thanks in advance
Andy C

**EDIT**
I have subsequently figured out that I can get this code to work if I convert the *data.frame* to a *data.table* before running the summarizing code:

```
dff <- as.data.table(dff)
```

Whether this code was successfully run previously is now in question, but at least we can move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You found your solution yourself, but for your understanding let me explain what this error message means.

What your error says is that you try to use `data.table` (from `library(data.table)`) code on a `data.frame` (base R). Despite sharing similar properties, these two objects are different. Notably, `data.table` provides an interface to do operations by reference rather than copying huge data structure, so it is most likely faster.

As you figured out, you need to run your code on a `data.table`that is you have to convert it somewhere.